# Different electric potentials paralyze ethernet between 2 houses

Tags: ethernet

I want to connect my LAN to a neighbour's house. Both houses are detached, so we ran cable  outdoors about 25m between the houses; the total cable run is 50m.

If I supply power to the end of UTP cable from the same house, ethernet works, but if powered on each side from particular house, it "connects" at 100 Mbit, but in reality the speed varies between 0 and few Mbit - unusable for surfing.

How can I solve this problem?  Would a UPS cancel the different potentials? I would like to avoid optics at first.  Wifi at 2.4GHz is very crowded, but 5GHz could be a solution.  However, I would like to fix the ethernet first, if possible.

Comment: Let's not assume this is a problem with electrical potentials yet... ethernet uses differential signalling across the pairs so it's fairly tolerant... The first thing you need to do is validate the integrity of your cable run. Take a laptop to the neighbor's house and be sure it's running on battery. Plug in your cable, and run about 500 pings to the laptop. If it pings clean, chances are good that the cable is alright... if you loose pings, then check the cable path in case it is picking up noise (like from motors, or florescent lighting).  Duplex mismatch is another possible problem.

Comment: Please do not cross post. [Same question on electrical engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83827/different-electric-potentials-paralyze-ethernet-between-2-houses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution - it was not about electric potentials... the ethernet ports of neighbour's ADSL modem were bad somehow - some of them had 50% packet loss on simple ping over 2m ethernet cable from a laptop... this seemed to have coused all the trouble. Swapped ADSL modem for another one and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have a problem with electrical potential now.

During some thunderstorm, you will.

IMHO, IME, fiber is the only way to run outside ethernet connections, for long term reliability and not blowing equipment up in thunderstorms.